# Subject/Object , Wh clause (noun clause)

Tags: grammaticality, clauses, wh-questions, noun-clause

S1: The plumber is Ben.

S2: Ben is the plumber.

As here, The above two sentences are equivalent.

So when we create wh- clause (noun clause)

Which one is right

> I don’t know [who is Ben].
>
> I don’t know [who Ben is].

Comment: "Who is Ben?" is a question. What you don't know is not a question, but a fact (who Ben is).

Comment: @KateBunting So the answer is "the first one is wrong and the second one is right"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I intended to convey.